# Tfs 2015 release mgmt - Task groups - not available in on-prem?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, release-management, ms-release-management

We have Tfs 2015 update 3 on-prem, however, we can't see the task group options in release management. Nor can we add artifact aliases.

Are these only in VSTS? The documentation at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks  suggests they might be in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task Groups will be shipped with the next release of TFS i.e. TFS 15 ( not 2015 ).

The RC2 version is available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs15-relnotes).